# Rename function in tidyverse doesnt work as expected

Tags: r

I have a problem renaming a variable in R.

```
dput(test)
structure(list(Accession = "tomato", Query = "Say1", `Hit type` = "specific"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

i've tried:

```
test %>%
    rename(Newquery = Query)
```

which resulted in :
Error in rename(., Newquery = Query) : unused argument (Newquery = Query)

solved:
at the beginning of the session i've loaded by mistake tidyverse and plyr instead of just tidyverse. As @Edward suggested, there's a problem with masking.

Comment: I wonder if you're affected by masking. Try: `test %>%
    dplyr::rename(Newquery = Query)`.

Comment: If you type: `?rename` does R give you a list of packages to choose from?

Comment: test %>% dplyr::rename(Newquery = Query) worked .

If i press ?rename:  

Help on topic 'rename' was found in the following packages:  

Modify names by name, not position.
(in package plyr in library /home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6)
Select/rename variables by name
(in package dplyr in library /home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6)  

So what's the problem my friend and how can i solve it? i dont remember i had similar problems with tidyverse functions in the past

Comment: Masking. You loaded plyr _after_ dplyr for this R session. This gives __plyr__ priority when functions are duplicated in your search path. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to **masking**.

If you have two or more packages loaded and there are duplicated function names, R will give priority to the package you loaded most recently.

There are a few simple solutions.

1. Unload (detach) from the package you don't need (in this case probably plyr).
   `detach(package:plyr)`
2. Load dplyr *after* plyr.

   `library(plyr)
    library(dplyr)`
3. Call the functions explicitly with the double colon. `dplyr::rename()`

Option 3 is cumbersome. Option 2 is really only a band-aid solution. Option 1 may be the best, or option 4: Don't load plyr at all.